# What is jscache script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I was developing a webpage and I included some scripts on it. When I try running it locally (using Chrome) code added (a script) at the end before the `</body>`.

```
<script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/jscache/fc48c8b8268e72e740.js"></script>
```

It is sound like a cache on my website.. because when I make some changes on my style-sheet the code won't work, and I need to hard refresh it.. sometimes empty cache and hard reload. In the past weeks I did not encounter this.

I don't included such script on my website or any related to it. Why was that? Did chrome browser automatically adding it? If yes, why? Is it vital?

Comment: Looks like you have an extension which is making money off you by forcing you to view ads after clicking on a link. What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: I will look on it..

Comment: To investigate this, I would first disable all your extensions and slowly add one extension at a time until you find a culprit.

Comment: It looks like "Chrome Currency Reporter" has a history of doing this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/xKg-fQHrKrg

Comment: @Gerrit0 One of my extension is responsible of creating this issue. I tried to disable my extensions one by one. And find out the reason.. Thank you.

Comment: Extension named: Spotiload